# ¿Cómo enviar con AJAX datos a la BD?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Uso `Javascript` para capturar la ubicación y necesito enviarla a la `BD` cuando de clic en un botón de la siguiente forma, pero no me los esta grabando en la `BD` debo usar `ajax` para que no me recargue la pagina y ademas que debe ser sin formulario de forma que al darle al botón haga el proceso de traer la ubicación y grabarlas en la `BD`, debe ser automático porque el usuario usa ese botón solo para desplegar un listado.
la idea es que guarde la ubicación del usuario con su nombre para consultarlas luego en otro rol que seria `admin`

```
$(function () {
     $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#encuentrame").click(function () {
        $('#encuentrame').prop("disabled", true);
             //Si el navegador soporta geolocalizacion
             if (!!navigator.geolocation) {
                 //Pedimos los datos de geolocalizacion al navegador
                 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
                     //Si el navegador entrega los datos de geolocalizacion los imprimimos
                     function (position) {
                         //window.alert("permite");
                         $("#lat").text(position.coords.latitude);
                         $("#lon").text(position.coords.longitude);
                         var element = document.getElementById('lat');
                         valor = element.innerHTML;
                         agregarDatos(valor);
                         console.log("Aquí se envía a la base de datos el valor de : " + valor);
                     },
                     //Si no los entrega manda un alerta de error
                     function () {
                         window.alert("nav no permitido");
                     }
                 );
             }
         });

function agregarDatos(valor) {
            usuario = '<?php echo $_SESSION['user_name']; ?>';
            datos = {
                usuario: usuario,
                respuesta: valor
            };
            console.log(datos);

            var request = $.ajax({
                url: "insertar.php", 
                method: "POST",
                data: datos,
                dataType: "json"
            });

            request.done(function (data) {
                console.log("Se agregaron los datos: " + data);
            });

            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert("Error petición Ajax: " + textStatus);
            });

        }

     });

 });
```

insertar.php

```
<?php 
/*Verificar que estén todos los datos*/
if (isset($_POST['usuario']) && !empty($_POST['usuario']) && isset($_POST['respuesta']) && !empty($_POST['respuesta'])) 
{
    $usuario = $_POST['usuario'];
    $respuesta = $_POST['respuesta'];
    //Datos de conexión a la base de datos
    $host       = "localhost";
    $usuario_db = "root"; //Había dos variables $usuario
    $clave      = "";
    $basedatos  = "login";
    $tabla      = "datos";

    // Conectar a la base
    //  la variable $myslqi contendrá el objeto con la conexión
    $mysqli = mysqli_connect($host, $usuario_db, $clave, $basedatos);

    /*Verificar si la conexión se realizó*/
    if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) 
    {
        $error="Error al conectar a MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
        $json=array(1=>$error);
    }

    $sql = "INSERT INTO $tabla (nombre, latitud) VALUES ('".$usuario."', '".$respuesta."')";
    if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {

    } else {

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: ¿La tabla solamente tiene esos dos campos?

Comment: En realidad son 3 nombre, latitud y longitud
por ahora solo quería guardar nombre y latitud

Comment: Y qué es lo que te trae la respuesta del servidor? Si no se esta insertando debe de mandar algún error.

Comment: request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus) {
                alert("Error petición Ajax: " + textStatus);
            });
y sale esto
Error petición Ajax: ERROR

Comment: El error entonces no está en el sql como tal, sino en la petición

Comment: Puede ser que no los esta enviando a insertar.php los datos si estan en la variable datos los veo con console.log(datos); pero no se si estan llegando a insertar.php

Comment: @SaulSalazar, Cámbiale el dataType: Json por Html, porque con el json, esta esperando una respuesta json, esto con la finalidad de que te muestre algo mas de información en tu error.

Comment: Hice el cambio pero sigue igual, Error petición Ajax: ERROR

Comment: puedes probar es vez de valor = element.innerHTML; de la siguente manera valor = element.innerText;

Comment: Por lado fijate en el explorador en Inspeccionar > Network ya que es un POST que esta enviando. Y tambien la consola para ver si hay algun error javascript

Comment: Me saca un error 403Forbidden

Comment: 403 forbidden es un error de cors o de algun otro tipo, por el cual no podes llegar a tu backend..

Comment: como lo resuelvo?

Comment: Listo resuelto, el problema estaba en mi carpeta views estaba restringida por eso el error 403 solo fue sacar insert.php y listo ya guarda todo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema era la ruta views/insertar.php que estaba restringida y arrojaba un error 403 Forbidden que no deja mandar los datos a la BD con cambiar la ruta o dar permisos a la carpeta VIEWS se arregla el problema

Comment: Excelente, siempre es bueno inspeccionar cuando tenes peticiones ajax.